# Stripe confirmCardSetup with custom card data for payment method

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

```
stripe.confirmCardSetup(clientSecret,
        {
          payment_method: {
            card: {
               number: this.state.form.values.number,
            exp_month: this.state.form.values.expiry.substring(0,2),
            exp_year: this.state.form.values.expiry.substring(3,5),
            cvc: this.state.form.values.cvc,
             },
            billing_details: {
              name: name,
            },
          },
        }
      ).then(function(result) {...})
```

I was trying to create a payment method that can be used later by the customer through stripe's confirmCardSetup, not using stripe elements but with card info (number, cvc, expiry date) passed into the payment method field. It didn't work, and I'm wondering if I can do something of this nature? (We're on react native and don't want to use tipsi-stripe)

Comment: Hi. I believe Elements are the only way to achieve this. I'm not seeing a `card.number` property on the `PaymentMethod` object, which would likely thwart any security built into the workflow. https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing with separate fields and can'y find any documentation online about it except for this SO question.

Comment: @Gillian can you please share sample source code link? Planning to implement the same

Answer (score 8):

I figured out how to make this work. Here's the solution in case anyone else comes across this same issue:

```
var paymentMethod = {
  payment_method: {
    card: this.cardNumberElement,
    billing_details: {
      name: this.billingNameText.getValue()
    }
  }
};

stripe.confirmCardSetup(setupIntentSecret, paymentMethod)
      .then(function(result) { ... });
```

This works if you assign the property `card` to the `cardElement` object you created using this code:

```
this.elements = this.stripe.elements();
this.cardNumberElement = this.elements.create('cardNumber');
this.cardNumberElement.mount('#card-number');
this.cardExpiryElement = this.elements.create('cardExpiry');
this.cardExpiryElement.mount('#card-expiry');
this.cardCvcElement = this.elements.create('cardCvc');
this.cardCvcElement.mount('#card-cvc');
```

The key is that you must create all the components from the same `elements` object. This will associate all of the components together and send all of the information from all of the objects over to the Stripe API.